# Add multiple columns based on existing columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have this kind of dataset:

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 sex= c('F', 'M', 'F', 'F'),
                 education = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 age = c(23, 34, 55, 77),  
                 q32_1= c(1, 5, 2, 4), 
                 q32_2= c(2, 3, 4, 3),
                 q22_1= c(3, 1, 2, 4), 
                 q22_2= c(2, 3, 1, 3),
                 q22_5= c(3, 5, 2, 4), 
                 q57_2= c(1, 2, 4, 3),
                )
```

I need to make new variables based on the variables starting with q, but I want to group the values; so its should be that all values in the q's that have value 1 or 2 then it should be YES in the new dataset, all with value 3 = NO, all with value 4,5 = IDK

So final dataset should be like this with the new variables

```
  ID sex   age q32_1 q32_2 q22_1 q22_2 q22_5 q57_2 q32_1_cat q32_2_cat q22_1_cat q22_2_cat q22_5_cat q57_2_cat
    1  F
    2  M
    3  F
    4  F
```

Comment: I think your final dataset has not copied/displayed properly - it just shows data for the `sex` column and nothing else.

Comment: Also, what do you want o do with the value 5s?

Comment: i just wanted to show the structure, but the 5 should be IDK as well

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also want "IDK" for value 5:

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(q32_1_cat = ifelse(q32_1 %in% c(1, 2), "YES", ifelse(q32_1 == 3, "NO", "IDK")),
         q32_2_cat = ifelse(q32_2 %in% c(1, 2), "YES", ifelse(q32_2 == 3, "NO", "IDK")),
         q22_1_cat = ifelse(q22_1 %in% c(1, 2), "YES", ifelse(q22_1 == 3, "NO", "IDK")),
         q22_2_cat = ifelse(q22_2 %in% c(1, 2), "YES", ifelse(q22_2 == 3, "NO", "IDK")),
         q22_5_cat = ifelse(q22_5 %in% c(1, 2), "YES", ifelse(q22_5 == 3, "NO", "IDK")),
         q57_2_cat = ifelse(q57_2 %in% c(1, 2), "YES", ifelse(q57_2 == 3, "NO", "IDK")))
```

If the value in the q column is 1 or 2, ifelse() assigns "YES" to the corresponding new categorical variable.
If the value in the q column is 3, ifelse() assigns "NO" to the corresponding new categorical variable.
If the value in the q column is 4, ifelse() assigns "IDK" to the corresponding new categorical variable

Comment: what if i have 50 q's variables - is there a way to make this easier? af for loop or something

Comment: a more extensible version would be to use `across(starts_with("q"), .... .names =  "{.col}_cat")

Comment: Can you show that in your answer, please, im new to R

Comment: @Hellihansen I added the "any number of q columns" version as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("q"), 
                           \(x) case_when(x == 1 ~ "YES",
                                          x == 2 ~ "YES",
                                          x == 3 ~ "NO",
                                          .default = "IDK"),
                           .names = "{.col}_cat"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *data.table*:

```
#custom function to convert levels
f <- function(x) factor(x = x,
                        levels = 1:5,
                        labels = c("YES", "YES", "NO", "IDK", "IDK"))

#columns to update starting with "q"
cols <- grep("^q", colnames(dt), value = TRUE)

#loop through columns update:
dt[, paste0(cols, "_cat") := lapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = cols ]

dt
#    ID sex education age q32_1 q32_2 q22_1 q22_2 q22_5 q57_2 q32_1_cat q32_2_cat q22_1_cat q22_2_cat q22_5_cat q57_2_cat
# 1:  1   F         A  23     1     2     3     2     3     1       YES       YES        NO       YES        NO       YES
# 2:  2   M         B  34     5     3     1     3     5     2       IDK        NO       YES        NO       IDK       YES
# 3:  3   F         C  55     2     4     2     1     2     4       YES       IDK       YES       YES       YES       IDK
# 4:  4   F         D  77     4     3     4     3     4     3       IDK        NO       IDK        NO       IDK        NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `data.table`-esque?

```r
nms <- grep("^q[0-9]", names(dt), value = TRUE)
dt[, paste0(nms, "_cat") := lapply(.SD, function(z) fcase(z == 1, "YES", z == 2, "YES", z == 3, "NO", default = "IDK")), .SDcols = nms]
dt
#       ID    sex education   age q32_1 q32_2 q22_1 q22_2 q22_5 q57_2 q32_1_cat q32_2_cat q22_1_cat q22_2_cat q22_5_cat q57_2_cat
#    <num> <char>    <char> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>    <char>    <char>    <char>    <char>    <char>    <char>
# 1:     1      F         A    23     1     2     3     2     3     1       YES       YES        NO       YES        NO       YES
# 2:     2      M         B    34     5     3     1     3     5     2       IDK        NO       YES        NO       IDK       YES
# 3:     3      F         C    55     2     4     2     1     2     4       YES       IDK       YES       YES       YES       IDK
# 4:     4      F         D    77     4     3     4     3     4     3       IDK        NO       IDK        NO       IDK        NO
```

Alternatively using a simple `dict` (named vector):

```r
dict <- c("1"="YES", "2"="NO", "3"="NO")
dt[, paste0(nms, "_cat") := lapply(.SD, function(z) fcoalesce(dict[as.character(z)], "IDK")), .SDcols = nms]
# same result
```